# Using "tell me" word on callI

Tags: grammar, politeness

I usually use the "tell me" on calls. For example when I pick up call I like to answer in this way:
"Yes John, tell me"

Is it a good practice to talk on call in this way?

Comment: I've never once heard this in my entire life. I would go so far as to say it is not English.

Comment: No. This is very impolite. You might also enjoy our sister site: [ell.se].

Comment: Is this a direct translation of what you use in your native language? Politeness words in any language tend to be weird when taken literally. E.g. "How are you?": why "how"? That makes no sense! Your "tell me" sounds rude in English, but in your language from constant use, might be unremarkable.

Answer (score 4):

It depends what effect you're trying to get and whether it's getting you that effect. Most likely, it's just annoying people -- particularly people you speak to often.

Using a non-standard reply where courtesy demands a standard one forces the listener to try to figure out whether you meant something special, distracting them from the flow of the conversation. While they're trying to figure out what it is you are asking them to tell you, they're probably losing the thought of what *they* wanted to tell *you*.

Comment: In movies, someone who answers the phone "Talk to me!" is usually portraying an abrupt, blunt person.